# Angular's $rootScope.$digest

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Reading this excellent book, *[Mastering Web Development in AngularJS](https://web.archive.org/web/20140122075939/http://www.packtpub.com/angularjs-web-application-development/book)*, I ran across this code:

```
var Restaurant = function ($q, $rootScope) {

var currentOrder;

this.takeOrder = function (orderedItems) {
    currentOrder = {
    deferred:$q.defer(),
    items:orderedItems
};
    return currentOrder.deferred.promise;
};
this.deliverOrder = function() {
    currentOrder.deferred.resolve(currentOrder.items);
    $rootScope.$digest();
};
this.problemWithOrder = function(reason) {
    currentOrder.deferred.reject(reason);
    $rootScope.$digest();
};
```

My understanding is that the `$rootScope.$digest();` calls are made in order to alert Angular that the `Promise`'s state has been updated.

Is my understanding correct? Also, is it necessary to make the above `$rootScope.$digest();` calls?

Comment: What version of AngularJS was the book written against?  I have never used `$rootScope.$digest();`, but I started with AngularJS version 1.0.x.  Typically you need to use `$scope.$apply()` when notifying AngularJS of data modification from outside of the AngularJS environment (example: jQuery event).  If the actions are triggered by a standard AngularJS directive (example: `ng-click`) then there is no need to call `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: the book uses `1.0.2` according to the sample code's `index.html` <header>.

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.$digest()` is what processes all of the `$watch` events that are on the current and children scope. It essentially manually tells the scope to check if a scope variable has changed. You don't generally want to use this when you are inside of a controller or a directive, because the `$scope.$apply()` function calls the `$digest` anyway and it is called when you mutate a scope variable.

Checkout this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `$rootScope.$digest` here because resolving/rejecting the promise will fire a `$rootScope.$digest` internally, as `$interval`,`$timeout`,and `$http` (after request finished) do that for you. And this `$digest` can throw errors of `$digest` already in progress.